# Declare a global variable in scala

Tags: scala

Is it possible to declare a global variable in this way?

if i run this snippet, i will encounter an error

```
object Test {
  val value -> error on this line for declaration issue
  def run() {
    value  = ... 
  }
def main(args: Array[String]) {
    run()
  }
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: You can declare value as `var`

Comment: @orid as var it can stay global?

Comment: Both var and val are in object scope. The difference is that val is immutable whereas var is mutable

Comment: Public `var` is one of the less Scala idiomatic feature.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could in theory do it using a **Trait**.
I'm not sure this is what you need though.

It would look like this:

```
trait MyTestTrait {
  val value: String
}

object MyTest extends MyTestTrait {
  val value = "yo!"
  def run = println(value)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No, that's not possible. You should do this:

```
object Test {
  val value = ...
}
```

Since your `run()` function does not take parameters, the contents of `value` can also be computed without it.

Answer (score 0):

you can add java classes in Scala ,
so you can create a class and put your variables in static { } method
and you can get access using private get methods .

```
package com.test.config

import com.typesafe.config.Config;
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory;

public class ConfigurationManager {

    private static String myLink;
 
    public static String GetMyLink()
    {
        return myLink;
    }

    static {
        Config config = ConfigFactory.load();
        myLink = config.getString("com.test.myLink");
    }
}
```